# How to use protected route in reactjs for msal authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to implement a protected route in my React web application, but I am receiving an error message: `Uncaught Error: [ProtectedRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>.`

In my application, I want to display a login popup for users when they first open the app if they have not yet signed in. However, I encountered a problem where users were able to access the page without signing in, so I tried to implement a protected router to prevent this and encounter with the error.

App.jsx

```
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <ProtectedRoute   path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/about" element={<About/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/explore" element={<Explore/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoute.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMsal, useIsAuthenticated } from '@azure/msal-react';

function ProtectedRoute({ element: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  const [popupOpened, setPopupOpened] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleLogin = async () => {
      try {
        const account = await instance.handleRedirectPromise();
        if (account) {
          setPopupOpened(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }

      const accounts = instance.getAllAccounts();
      if (!isAuthenticated && !popupOpened && accounts.length === 0) {
        try {
          await instance.loginPopup();
          setPopupOpened(true);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    };

    handleLogin();
  }, [instance, isAuthenticated, popupOpened]);

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Route {...rest} element={<Component />} />;
  }

  return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { msalConfig } from './services/Config.js';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```